# Sorting an array containing dates and rearranging index

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've created custom post in my wordpress website. In this post, I create events with a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.
I then want to display the next 3 events on my website.

I've created the following array:

```
Array{
    [0]=> Array(
        [EventDate] => 2014/03/14
        [TimestampEvent] => 1394582400
        [DeltaEvent] => 22327
    )
    [1]=> Array(
        [EventDate] => 2014/03/15
        [TimestampEvent] => 1394582401
        [DeltaEvent] => 22328
    )
    [2]=> Array(
        [EventDate] => 2014/03/16
        [TimestampEvent] => 1394582402
        [DeltaEvent] => 22329
    )
}
```

I would like to:

- Disregard the event that have already happened;
- Sort my future events from the nearest to the furthest;
- Display the next 3 events on my website.

I've pretty much already sorted the last point. The issue is more about sorting my event.

So far, I've tried the uksort() function, but I couldn't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Edited;

@Bram solution is working great!
The only thing is that the structure of the Array $next is :

```
Array{
    [0]=> Array(
        [EventDate]=> 2014/03/16
        [TimestampEvent] => 1394582402
        [DeltaEvent] => 22329
    )
}
```

How do I acces the EventDate keys from the $next array? I've tried $next[0][0] but it surprisingly didn't work.

Re-Edited;

```
$next[$i][DateEvenement]
```

I'm nearly done! Now everything is displaying on the website every date is good! The only thing is that the 3 nearest dates display in the order that they've been added in the wordpress. My code is the following:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query('post_type=event');
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();                                     
for($i=0;$i<count($next);$i++){                                         
    if(get_field('date') == $next[$i][DateEvent]){ ?>
        <div>  
            <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
}
endwhile;?>
```

The issue is probably from my query but I'm unsure on how to fix this.

Thanks for the help!

Re-Re-Edited;

@Myself

I've done it mom! It's working like a charm. I only had to fix my query. This is the code I used:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($next);$i++){
     $args = array('numberposts' => 1,'post_type' => 'evenement','meta_key' => 'date','meta_value' => $next[$i][DateEvenement]);
     $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
     if( $the_query->have_posts() ){
         while ( $the_query->have_posts() ){                                                
            $the_query->the_post();                                            
            if(get_field('date') == $next[$i][DateEvenement]){ ?>                                                    
                <div>                                                       
                    <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>                                                 
                    <p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>                                                              
                </div>                                                                      
<?php
            }
        }
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should get you near the answer...

**Disregard the event that have already happened;**

```
$new_data = array_filter($data, function ($a) { return $a['TimestampEvent']>time(); });
```

**Sort my future events from the nearest to the furthest;**

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['TimestampEvent']==$b['TimestampEvent']) return 0;
    return ($a['TimestampEvent'] < $b['TimestampEvent']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

**Display the next 3 events on my website.**

```
$next = array_slice($data, 0, 3);
```

Comment: I edited my post with another question. Can you please check it out?

Comment: Looks like you fixed it yourself, good job for fixing it & posting the answer!